# CONTRAST: Verb Tampering Weakness /WEB-INF/web.xml file

Tags: http, web.xml, http-verbs

Getting Verb Tampering Weakness after scanning app with Contrast tool for  in web.xml file.

[Code : Verb tampering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE4UW.png)

Please suggest some solutions to avoid this vulnerability ?

I tried couple of solutions like

Replacing  with .
Removing  but can't do it its required for our application otherwise it will deny for all the URLs.

got on suggestion to remove  but if we will remove  then how are we restricting verbs?